# I want to run two queries in script. Oracle. Need help

Tags: oracle

i have following two queries, one is create procedure query and other is the call to the same procedure.

they both run fine when running indiviually, but when i try to run them together in one go i get errors: like executed with warnings and the results are not proper with that.

can you please tell me how can i achieve this? may be it has to do soem thing with execute immediate  , but i am new to this so dont know how to convert my first query to be executed with execute immediate.

Thanks in advance
Ashish

```
CREATE or replace PROCEDURE DP_DROP_FKEY_PROC (NS IN varchar2,
NM IN varchar2, FK IN varchar2)
IS
  S VARCHAR2(150) := '';
  I NUMBER;
BEGIN
  I := 0;
  SELECT COUNT(*) INTO I FROM ALL_CONSTRAINTS C
  WHERE (C.OWNER = NS) AND (C.TABLE_NAME = NM) AND (C.CONSTRAINT_NAME = FK) ;
  IF (I = 1) THEN
    S := 'ALTER TABLE "' || NS || '"."' || NM || '" DROP CONSTRAINT "' || FK || '"';
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE S;
  END IF;
END;


CALL DP_DROP_FKEY_PROC('SomeOwnerName', 'TableName', 'ConstraintName');
```

Comment: How can you run the second query `individually` if it calls the procedure? What error do you get?

Comment: i first execute first query which will create the procedure and then i execute the second query which will call the procedure and it worked fine in two steps. but i want to execute both the queries in one go. 
when i do that i get following error :

   Warning: execution completed with warning
PROCEDURE DP_DROP_FKEY_PROC Compiled.

Comment: Warning: execution completed with warning
PROCEDURE DP_DROP_FKEY_PROC Compiled.

Comment: €Ashish: see my updated answer. BTW: In that case it is better to edit your question and provide additional information, not add it as comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried the procedure and it worked.

Make sure to pass all the parameters **uppercase** as `ALL_CONSTRAINTS` holds them uppercase, so that would be
`CALL dp_drop_fkey_proc('SOMEOWNERNAME', 'TABLENAME', 'CONSTRAINTNAME');`
in your example.

If this does not help, please provide the error you get.

**EDIT**:

The way you do it, it will always be two steps:

1. Create the procedure
2. Run it

Once the procedure is compiled, you can run it again and again with different parameters.

If you want to do it with one call, the only way that makes sense is to call

```
ALTER TABLE "SOMEOWNERNAME"."TABLENAME" DROP CONSTRAINT "CONSTRAINTNAME"
```

**EDIT2**:

Maybe I did not understand what you wanted to do. Can you try to add a slash character `/` in the line after your `END;`?

```
-- [...]
END;
/

CALL DP_DROP_FKEY_PROC('SomeOwnerName', 'TableName', 'ConstraintName');
```

Comment: Thanks EDIT2: worked for me. It was that / i was looking for between two statements.

Thanks